# Переключение между кнопками

Tags: javascript, button

Есть 4 кнопки:

```html
<button>Button-1</button>
<button>Button-2</button>
<button>Button-3</button>
<button>Button-4</button>
```

Надо чтобы при нажатии на любую из них менялся цвет фона, у этой кнопки, и пропадал у другого. По умолчанию цвет фона изменён у первого

Comment: для начала покажите что уже сделано и поясните, где именно и с какими именно трудностями в реализации вы столкнулись?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно вам для каждой кнопки назначать отдельную функцию. А если завтра кол-во кнопок изменится, например будет не 4, а 40? Для каждой кнопки отдельно будете функцию вешать? Да и не стоит менять CSS св-ва через JS без острой необходимости, для этого есть CSS и классы, которые мы можем легко переключать через JS. Вот один из правильных способов, как вам надо реализовать поставленную задачу:

```js
const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll('.btn')];

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('.btn.active').classList.remove('active');
    button.classList.add('active');
  })
})
```

```css
.btn.active {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button class='btn active'>Button 1</button>
<button class='btn'>Button 2</button>
<button class='btn'>Button 3</button>
<button class='btn'>Button 4</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
<script>

document.querySelector(".button-1").style.background = "red"; // устанавливаем цвет первой кнопки на красный
document.querySelector(".button-3").style.background = "green"; // устанавливаем цвет второй кнопки на зеленый

function clickBtn1() {
  document.querySelector(".button-1").style.background = "green";
  document.querySelector(".button-3").style.background = "red";
}

function clickBtn3() {
  document.querySelector(".button-1").style.background = "red";
  document.querySelector(".button-3").style.background = "green";
}

document.querySelector(".button-1").onclick = clickBtn1;
document.querySelector(".button-3").onclick = clickBtn3;

</script>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Адаптировала под себя, это то что нужно.